# install parse failed inconsistent certificates, even though app is already deleted

Tags: android

I had to reinstall Android Studio and rebuild my app from the ground due to some errors with the gradle. However, when I want to run the app on my phone, it gives the 'install parse failed inconsistent certificates' error. Even though I already deleted the app from my phone, and no traces of it can be found on it. When I run my app on a emulator it works fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: do project clean and rebuild. Start from it. May help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this isn't working. Maybe somehow there are still some traces left of my app on the phone? It says it installs in /data/local/tmp/com.mywebsite.myapp, where I still found a file/folder by that name through adb, but even when I deleted that through adb I'm getting the same error:/

Comment: Ha I don't know why but apparently it was just not showing up in the app drawer. When I went to settings->apps it was still there. Kinda stupid haha. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am glad you fixed your issue :)

Comment: This happened to me because I didn't uninstall it for all users. Do you have multiple users on your device?